# What is wrong with my following vector plot

Tags: vector-calculus

I am trying to plot the following:

```
VectorPlot[{Abs[
   D[((-3 Cos[Sin[t]])/(Sqrt[
         9 Cos^2[Sin[t]] + 4 Sin^2[Sin[t]]]))/(Sqrt[
       9 Cos[Sin[t]]^2 + 4 Sin^2 [Sin[t]]]), t]], 
  Abs[D[((2 Sin[Sin[t]])/(Sqrt[
         9 Cos^2[Sin[t]] + 4 Sin^2[Sin[t]]]))/(Sqrt[
       9 Cos^2[Sin[t]] + 4 Sin^2[Sin[t]]]), t]]}, {t, -10, 10}]
```

I get this error:

[image]

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong? It is probably something ridiculously simple, and if that is the case I apologize. Just really a beginner trying to figure this programming out.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One syntax problem is `Cos^2[Sin[t]]` this should be `Cos[Sin[t]]^2` (probably). Next, it doesn't look like `VectorPlot` is the right plotting function because you've only got one variable `t`. Assuming these guesses are right, you can plot:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Abs[
    D[((-3 Cos[Sin[t]])/(Sqrt[
          9 Cos[Sin[t]]^2 + 4 Sin[Sin[t]]^2]))/(Sqrt[
        9 Cos[Sin[t]]^2 + 4 Sin[Sin[t]]^2]), t]], 
   Abs[D[((2 Sin[Sin[t]])/(Sqrt[
          9 Cos[Sin[t]]^2 + 4 Sin[Sin[t]]^2]))/(Sqrt[
        9 Cos[Sin[t]]^2 + 4 Sin[Sin[t]]^2]), t]]}], {t, -10, 10}]
```

Or perhaps what you were looking for was `ParametricPlot` (Just replace `Plot`).